# Is't a correct observation that No norm on $B[0,1]$ can be found to make $C[0,1]$ open in it?

Tags: normed-spaces

There's a problem in my [*text*](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Topology_of_Metric_Spaces.html?id=ehZ_LRmG3JMC&redir_esc=y) which reads as:

> Show that $C[0,1]$ is not an open subset of $(B[0,1],\|.\|_\infty).$

I've already shown in a previous example that for any open subspace $Y$ of a normed linear space $(X,\|.\|),~Y=X.$ Even though using this result this problem turns out to be immediate the sup-norm is becoming immaterial.

### And I can't believe what I'm left with:

***No norm on $B[0,1]$ can be found to make $C[0,1]$ open in it.***

---

Is this a correct observation?

Comment: Why can you not believe it?

Comment: Because so simply I get to conclude such a huge statement.

Comment: It's not a huge statement.

Comment: I meant to say I didn't expect to predict about all possible norms so easily.

Comment: But *any* theorem about normed spaces is a statement about all possible norms. Do you have this reaction whenever you read a theorem?

Comment: I'm yet to study normed spaces. This problem appears in the text as an exercise of metric space. The author didn't discuss any theorem on norm. Defining norm & how it generates a metric he simply gives the problem.

Comment: Option 1: what is the span of an open ball in a normed vector space? Option 2: if $V$ is an open subspace in a normed vector space $X$, then $X\setminus V=\bigcup_{x\not \in V} x+V$ is open, so connectedness of $X$ implies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is actually true under more general settings. It seems convenient to talk about [topological vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space), of which normed spaces are a very special kind.

So let $X$ be a topological vector space and $Y$ be an *open* subspace. So we know $Y$ contains some open set.

Since the topology on topological vector spaces are translation invariant (that is, $V$ is open if and only if $V+x$ is open for all $x\in X$, you can check this in normed spaces), we know $Y$ contains some open neighborhood of the origin, say $0\in V\subset Y$.

Another interesting fact about topological vector spaces is that for any open neighborhood $W$ of the origin, one has \begin{equation}
X=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}nW.
\end{equation}Again you might check this for normed spaces. Apply this to our $V$, and note that $Y$ is closed under scalar multiplication, we have \begin{equation}
X=\cup nV\subset \cup nY=Y.
\end{equation}

So we have just proved

> The only open subspace is the entire space.

Note: If $S$ is a subset of a vector space, for a point $x$ and a scalar $\alpha$ we define \begin{equation}
x+S:=\{x+s|s\in S\}
\end{equation} and \begin{equation}
\alpha S:=\{\alpha s|s\in S\}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Your "interesting fact about topological vector spaces" seems to make some assumptions about the underlying field. What are they exactly?

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen I assume we are talking about vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I do not know any topological vector spaces built on fields other that $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen Do we really want to do functional analysis on discrete fields?

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen What is the use of topological vector spaces if one is not doing functional analysis? XD

Answer (score 0):

This is true.  Indeed, you can show more:

> Let $X$ be a normed vector space.  If $E \subseteq X$ is a linear subspace which is open, then $E = X$.

My guess is this follows from the same argument you already have.

Comment: Er, the OP explicitly states this is the argument they used.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: Oh, I missed that sentence.

Comment: If you want to generalize: a proper subgroup of a connected topological group has empty interior. That's still very easy.